# How install Emacs 28 from OFFICIAL REPOSITORY?

Tags: linux, install

Linux Mint 21.3

I installed Emacs like this:

apt-install emacs

It's success installed ... but it's version 27.

But I want to install Emacs 28... from **OFICIAL REPOSITORY**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your official repository apparently only has Emacs 27, so you'll have to use something different.

Comment: This question is about Mint, not about Emacs.

Comment: @NickD What Linux distributive have Emacs 28? Maybe CentOS, Debian or smt else?

Comment: All I know is that Fedora 37 has Emacs 28.2.

Comment: @a_subscriber If you want the latest versions of the software you use, you should install a rolling release distro (e.g., Manjaro, openSUSE Tumbleweed, ...). But indeed, this question is absolutely not related to Emacs.